# Full AspectJ support in Spring

Tags: java, spring, aspectj

I'd like to weave an advice on a method that is NOT part of a Spring bean (Spring Boot 1.4.4.RELEASE) :

```
@Component
@Aspect
...
@Around("execution(public * com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo.getId())")
```

I added aspectjrt and spring-instrument (??) dependencies

I added @EnableAspectJAutoProxy and @EnableLoadTimeWeaving(aspectjWeaving = AspectJWeaving.ENABLED) annotations

I added VM arguments:

```
-javaagent:d:\.m2\repository\org\springframework\spring-instrument\4.3.6.RELEASE\spring-instrument-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar
-javaagent:d:\.m2\repository\org\aspectj\aspectjweaver\1.8.9\aspectjweaver-1.8.9.jar
```

The bean is handled (postconstruct log) but the execution isn't intercepted.
Does anyone has a clue on something I could miss ? Thx in advance

Comment: I assume you have carefully studies the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw) and also have a properly configured `META-INF/aop.xml`? You should also be aware of the fact that `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` is only used for proxy-based Spring AOP, not for LTW with full AspectJ. You only use `@EnableLoadTimeWeaving` there.

Comment: I thought that @EnableLoadTimeWeaving(aspectjWeaving = AspectJWeaving.ENABLED) was avoiding the need for an XML definition

Comment: It avoids the need for Spring-related XML definition. `aop.xml` is AspectJ-related and only needed for LTW, not for compile-time weaving. AspectJ is completely independent of Spring, you merely use it within the context of a Spring container, but it still is a separate tool.

Comment: Thx @kriegaex that worked indeed. But in the process I lost my aspect as a Spring bean (obviously). I need to get a property to be code complete. I'll try to figure it out

Comment: Yes, the documentation link I provided explains how to get your LTW aspects integrated into the Spring dependency injection etc. lifecycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is the trick for those interested, a singleton pattern is handling access to a singleton for both LTW and Spring, so it can be injected with Spring dependencies after being weaved by LTW:

```
@Configuration
@Aspect
public class MyAspect {
    @Value("${mycompany.property}")
    private String myKey;

    @Around("execution(public * com.mycompany.NotASpringean.getProperty())")
    public String weave(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {
        String value = (String) jp.proceed();
        // transform the value thx to injected myKey value
        return value;
    }

    @Bean("post-construct-aspect")
    public MyAspect init() {
        return MyAspect.aspectOf(); // get existing instance via factory method
    }

    private static MyAspect instance = new MyAspect();
    /** Singleton pattern used by LTW then Spring */
    public static MyAspect aspectOf() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `@Pointcut` annotation too like this:

```
@Pointcut("execution(public * com.netflix.appinfo.InstanceInfo.getId())")
public void pointcut() {}

@Around("pointcut()")
public Object whatever(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws {...}
```

Comment: Nonsense, both ways to do it are equivalent.